# Asterisk initiate call

Tags: asterisk, phone-call

can I initiate an outgoing call with Asterisk by an other way than using callfiles?

Answer (score 0):

you can also initiate originate command on asterisk cli. or can use dial-plan Dial application for making more interactive

Answer (score 0):

using asterisk-manager node-js module then

```
var Ami = require('asterisk-manager');
var ami = Ami("5038", "127.0.0.1", "admin", "AMIpassword", true);

//call someone and move him to ivr-4

ami.action({
    'action':'originate',
    'channel':'SIP/trunk/0875421989',
    'context':'ivr-4',
    'CallerID': '0123456789',
    'exten':'s',
    'priority':1,
    'async': true,
    'Codecs': 'g729'
}, function(err, res) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(res);
});
```

the number in channel going to be dialed
The CallerID is the number that should appear to the receiver
the context is where you are sending the receiver after call answered